# Django upload files to directory and filename in database

Tags: python, django, forms

**Ques1:** I want to upload my files into a custom directory and my filename will be saved in database. My files are uploading nicely even filename saving in database but problem is my files are going to tmp directory.

So how may I set my upload directory path in code?? My desired directory is `MEDIA_ROOT` which is `/static/uploads/`

This is what I have tried so far (multiple file processing)

```
for file_name in request.FILES.getlist('project_file'):
  full_filename = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, '/', file_name)
  project_files = ProjectFile.objects.create(file_name=file_name,project_id=proj_id)
  project_files.save()
```

but this is showing following error

> 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'replace'

my `ProjectFile` model

```
class ProjectFile(models.Model):
project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
file_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.id
```

**Ques2:** I need example or demo of django edit form done by `Form` class not `ModelForm`

I am new in django. Please help

Answer (score 0):

`os.path.join` adds, the '/' characters on its own.  that line should read

```
full_filename = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, file_name)
```

I don't understand your error- you said the files were getting uploaded correctly but to the wrong directory, then posted a fragment of a stack trace that implies the method is failing :)  That looks like something wrong with your model object- include the stack trace line that tells you which line the failure is on, and include the model code and we'll look at the error as well.

Comment: See my model. question revised. however my code works when I remove the `full_filename = os....` this line but files are going to wrong directory. what is the professional way to set custom upload directory?